# how to create a very long INSERT sql INTO EXCEL

Tags: sql, oracle

oracle : how to create a very long INSERT sql INTO EXCEL
prompt excel gives : your sql is very large , use concatenate function

plz guide me on how to do this

example

```
="insert into customers(20 columns one after another) values('" &B3 &"','" & C3 & "','"&D3&"'.........20th value);
```

Comment: Couldn't this be achieved with a cursor? Or some kind of batch processing?

Answer (score 1):

With these values in your Excel table:

```
A1 = INSERT INTO mytable(id, col2, col3, col4, col5) VALUES ('
A2 = '','
```

And data in A4:E4, like this:

```
A4 = testID
B4 = value
C4 = value2
D4 = value3
E4 = value4
```

You can build another column like this:

```
G4 = =CONCATENATE($A$1,A4,$A$2,B4,$A$2,C4,$A$2,D4,$A$2,E4,"');")
```

Which evaluates to this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable(id, col2, col3, col4, col5) VALUES ('testID','value','value2','value3','value4');
```

Using the references makes adding additional columns easier in the future since you won't have to remember to "Fill Down" the full column of formula text after you make changes to it.

Comment: one question... can the excel popup may appear because of column names(20 in total) being of 35 char each..summing up to 35*20 characters

Comment: `CONCATENATE` will support up to 255 text strings, so if you have more than 126 or so columns (since each column value and quotation/comma are needed for each column) you'll need to build the statement in parts. The output in the cell is fine as long as it's not longer than the text limit Excel 2010 has of 32,767 characters, which shouldn't be an issue for a SQL `INSERT` statement!

Answer (score 0):

Use the Excel CONCATENATE function instead of the concatenation symbol &.

```
=CONCATENATE("insert into customers(20 columns one after another) values('", B3, "','", C3, "','", D3, "'.........20th value")
```

Comment: THANKS FOR THE REPLY...ONE LAST QUESTION

Comment: CONCATENATE("insert into customers(20 columns one after another) values('", B3, "','", C3, "','", D3, "'......... ",T2,"')");

Comment: WILL THIS WORK...OR plz guide me